# AJAX and PHP, wont send data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have kind of a weird problem, which i can't seem to solve.

What i am trying to do, is to call a jQuery function on one page, send the argument of that function to another .php-file on the same server, have that php file read the variable, and then insert it into a database.

The function trigger is placed on a div, and looks like this:

```
<div class="add_button" onclick="addImg('<?php echo $value[id]; ?>');">
```

The function itself looks like this:

```
function addImg(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "addImgs.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"id" : id}
        });

        console.log("Function called with ID: " + id);
}
```

I am using the console to try and debug a little here, and the console.log()-function is being executed correctly. The log also give me an error 500 if the "url" does not exist.

Lastly, my php-code of addImgs.php looks like this:

```
<?php

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "DB_name");

$query = "INSERT INTO imgs (id) VALUES ($id)";
$result = $conn->query($query);

$conn->close();

?>
```

This .php-file works just fine, if i add

```
?id=123
```

to the end of it's url, and a value of "123" is added to the table in the database.

So my assumption is that the problem is the connection between the AJAX function, and the PHP-file.

Please Help :)

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for more clues. Is what is sent what is expected? what is status? is path what is expected etc etc. This will help isolate server side from client side problems

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how to do that?
I havent really worked with that before.

If you want to take a look yourself, the page with the function is the following:
http://projects.mn-web.dk/instafetcher/admin.php?p=dzehas

Comment: hit F12 on keyboard.... start exploring ...look for network tab. then make a request and will see it at the end

Comment: I suspect it is calling the wrong URL. Try using an absolute URL and test.

Comment: is making request with a 200 status but nothing returned...send something back something based on status of insert Also guessing you may be duplicating ID's ... will db accept that?

Comment: @LukeFranklin That makes no sense at all, as they are in the same folder, and besides, it didn't do anything :/

Comment: The fun things is, that it has worked before, the exact same script and php-file, when using the php file to write the info to a .txt file :/

Comment: need to look on network or net tab...what browser?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, the db will accept dupes, i have it set to that, as long as i am testing :)
I am using Chrome

Comment: @user2140209 Just because they are in the same folder doesn't mean AJAX is calling the correct URL.

Comment: Try replacing the contents of the php file with a simple echo then use the Network tab in Chrome's dev tools to see if you can see the result.

Comment: add some error handling for the query and also add some output based on insert success

Comment: wow, this Network tool is brilliant!
I made an echo with the id i pass, and is is showing up in the response..
So the php-file gets the id variable, which means the problem lies in the the php script inside... it is just weird that it works when i add the parameter directly in the url :/

Comment: Allright, so far so good.
When returing the mysql error i get the following:

    Unknown column '828281229958329915_2834748' in 'field list'

But how does that add up, looking at my php-script?

Why does it think "id" is $id?

Comment: there is a lot more under the hood at F12...get to know it

Answer (score 2):

In your question you say that the variable name is `id`, but on the actual website you gave a link to the name is `img_id`.

```
function addImg(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://projects.mn-web.dk/instafetcher/addImgs.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"img_id" : id}
        });

        console.log("Function called with ID: " + id);
}
```

Are you sure your server side script also expects `img_id`? In particular, are you sure in the actual PHP script you have this line:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['img_id'];
```

and not this:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Also note that your image ids are not integers:

```
img_id="828281229958329915_2834748"
```

So make sure that the type of `id` in `imgs` is `varchar` or something else that can store strings, and not `int` or `bigint`.

Update: as Ivan pointed out in a comment, since `img_id` is a string, not an integer, your `INSERT` query is invalid, it needs to enclose the id into quotes. One simple way to do that is:

```php
$query = "INSERT INTO imgs (id) VALUES (\"".mysqli_real_escape_string($id)."\")";
```

But a more proper way is to use prepared statements:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Also, the ID must be quoted in the query if it's a string.